# Using Cauchy's theorem to entire function $e^{-z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Using Cauchy's theorem to entire function $e^{-z^2}$

[image]

how to find these values i dont how to draw diagram so i added picture

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2} e^{2c z}dz = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(z-c)^2+c^2}dz$. Can you apply Cauchy integral theorem to this last expression ?

Comment: @reuns..sorry i something missing